Why the log function is so important on the plane?
I am studying right now some Complex Analysis and I have seen the importance of the (complex) logarithm function in almost every subject in it. Now I'm intrigued with that (possible) relation between $log$ and some "planar things".
Firstly, some years ago when studying calculus and some flux integrals, I tried to "derive" the Coulomb's Law in 2D using the Gauss's Law from Maxwell's Equations and it gave me some $log$ function for the potential. It was actually $U(r)=\frac{-q}{2\pi \epsilon_0}ln|r|$.
Reading ahlfors, we can define the rules of square root via the $log$ function and because of that we can have analytic branches of the square root in simply-connected regions, so we can conclude the riemann mapping theorem for simply-connected regions. Also (in the Ahlfors too) is treated about Green's Functions in the plane using the $log$ function (but this part I haven't studied yet).
In the end of Conway's first book is also said that "In many ways the study of analytic function theory can be considered as the study of the logarithm function"
Lastly, I have also read some spoilers about PDE's and the Dirichlet Problem, and in the plane the Fundamental Solution of Laplace's Equation is some $log$ function, exactly when $n=2$ (read that in Evans's PDE book). I also heard about some Potential Theory and the $log$ potential in the plane.
So since years ago I have this question, and now this only gets bigger. There is some book or theory that explains this (intrinsic) relation? Is it something that can be understood? Or is it just coincidence?

A basic reason : $\log(z)=\log(re^{i \theta})=\log(r)+i \theta$ : $\log$ allows to "realize" the phase (=argument) as an imaginary part, therefore allows to "work" easily on the phase.

We also have the argument principle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle

another reason is that for an analytic function $|f|$ (and hence the zeroes of $f$) is a difficult function to understand (not being analytic etc) but $\log |f|$ is a real harmonic near all points where $f \ne 0$ (and subharmonic near the zeroes when defined to be $-\infty$ there) and lots of useful properties (mean value theorem etc) apply to it that allow us to get a handle on $|f|$ and even on the zeroes of $f$ then; also $\arg f$ (the imaginary part of $\log f$ which generally is multivalued is important too as noted above in other comments but that is considerably more difficult to deal)
